# Adding activeX Combobox untill the last full line

Tags: excel, combobox, activex, excel-2007, vba

how can i add activeX combobox into a column "List Name" untill the last line of a grid? knowing that in the grid the only column that is always full  with values is "C Type"

I tried this :

```
For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        With Ws
            'adding the validation dropdown
             Col_num = .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
             Set MyRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, Col_num)).Cells.Find("List Name")
             Set FullRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, Col_num)).Cells.Find("C Type")

             'LastLine = .Range(FullRange).End(xlDown).Row
             LastLine = .Cells(2, FullRange).End(xlDown).Row

            Do Until IsEmpty(LastLine)
                If Not MyRange Is Nothing Then
                    With Ws.Columns(MyRange.Column).Validation
                     .Delete
                     .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                      xlBetween, Formula1:=Liste
                      .IgnoreBlank = True
                      .InCellDropdown = True
                    End With
                End If
             Loop
        End With
    Next Ws
```

but it gives an error "method range of object _worksheet failed" in this line:

LastLine = .Range(FullRange).End(xlDown).Row . 
When I tried the following it gives me the error "type mismatch"
LastLine = .Cells(2, FullRange).End(xlDown).Row

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
LastLine = .Cells(.Rows.Count, FullRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row
```

Revised full code:

```
For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    With Ws
        'adding the validation dropdown
        Col_num = .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
        Set myrange = .Rows(1).Find("List Name")
        If Not myrange Is Nothing Then
            Set fullrange = .Rows(1).Find("C Type")
            If Not fullrange Is Nothing Then
                'LastLine = .Range(FullRange).End(xlDown).Row
                lastline = .Cells(.Rows.Count, fullrange.Column).End(xlUp).Row

                With .Range(.Cells(2, myrange.Column), .Cells(lastline, myrange.Column)).Validation
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                         xlBetween, Formula1:=Liste
                    .IgnoreBlank = True
                    .InCellDropdown = True
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next Ws
```

Comment: I get the Error 91 object variable or with block variable not set .. it perhaps a problem on FullRange.column

Comment: That means that 'C Type' isn't found. Should it be present on all sheets? What should the code do if it isn't there?

Comment: not in all sheets of the workbook, but whenever there's C type column i need to add the combobox untill the last line !! is there a way for it please?

Comment: Try the revised version I just posted.

Comment: hmm no errors but the combobox is still out of the grid :(

Comment: It workssss, i had to remove the existing combobox after the previous execution, and now it's working well...Thanks a lot Rory :)

Comment: Oh one more question please, if i add a new line, i will have to re execute the macro right? can't it go automatically to the last line without having to re execute?

Comment: If you convert the range to a Table, it will automatically add the DV as it expands.

Comment: hmm...well i'll just leave it that way...Thanks for your help ;)